# Differenect ear from maven and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, ear

I have a maven project. Then I use mvn package, I get a ear file. I manually deploy it in WAS and it's worked.

But then I use Eclipse:

1. Export -> EAR file and manually deploy it's not work
2. Add project to WAS Server through Eclipse -> it's not work

What is the problem?

Comment: Compare 2 ears (mvn and Eclipse). Also describe what means "not work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Properties>Deployment Assembly, check if Maven Dependencies are present
It should look like:
[image]

If not present, add them via Add button.

Comment: Thks for answer, it's help! Then I use Import->EAR file and manually deploy on WAS it's work! Then I add EAR through Servers->WAS->Add and Remove->Add..then not working((( What the problem? Thanks alot!